# Converting JSON data before displaying in HTML

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I have some data being returned in this format:

```
[{
label: "Store Name",
address: "123 Somewhere Blvd",
city: " Atlanta",
state: "11",
zip: "30333"
}]
```

Id like to know if there is a way to convert the "state" portion to the states name instead of its ID number. **I have a table in my database that matches up the states with the ID's and I've been able to convert the states in php using PHP.** I did read somewhere that I cannot place php code inside of my jQuery code so im a bit stuck there.

In my example I am pulling a list of stores using an ajax autocomplete script and I am processing my output using the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
if (searchValue.length > 3) {
  var acs_action = 'autocompletesearch';

  $.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: MyAcSearch.url+'?action='+acs_action+'&term=' + searchValue,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
      name: searchValue
    },
    success: function (results) {
      var data = $.parseJSON(results); 

      if (data.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          var item = data[i];
          html += '<li>';
          html += '<div class="row">';
          html += '<div class="col-sm-9">';
          html += ' <h3>' + item.label + '</h3>' ;
          html += ' <span>' + item.city + ' , ' + item.state + ' , ' + item.zip + '</span>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '</div>';
          html += '</li>';
        }
      }
    }
  });
} 
}
```

The results are returning as expected with the ID number instead of the state name. Is there a way to capture the state id value and convert it to the State name before displaying? Ive tried researching a few different things but I feel like I am headed in the wrong direction. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

****I may be going about this the wrong way entirely. Any direction would be appreciated****

Comment: yes there is, SQL join statement will help you to join each tuple with a specific state id with the corresponding tuple in states table, http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am familiar with JOINS. Would I be able to apply a JOIN within my AJAX Request?

Comment: you are mixing things here, the AJAX request is a normal HTTP request to the server except that it can be done asynchronously (you don't need to refresh the browser, it's like you have sent some one to bring you some stuff while you play in the browser), so you can do what ever you want at the server side (the query can contain selects, joins, sort ... **any query supported by the db driver**)

Comment: so you just need to open the file `MyAcSearch.url+'?action='+acs_action+'&term=' + searchValue`, modify the query so that it returns the state name too

Answer (score 0):

If you control the source of the data (whatever is sending `state: "11"`), then your best option would be to update that script to return the state name with or instead of the state ID.

If you don't have control over the source of the data, one option would be to create an array of all your state ID/names in PHP, JSON-encode that array and print it out as javascript, and then look up the appropriate state name by ID when necessary:

```
<?php
$array = [..., '11'=>'Delaware', '12'=>'Florida', ...];
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        var States = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;
        </script>

        ...

        <script>
        function myFunction() {
            ...
            html += ' <span>' + item.city + ' , ' + States[item.state] + ' , ' + item.zip + '</span>';
            ...
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    ...
</html>
```